# Google Analytics: event tracking vs. virtual pageviews

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

Goal: a client would like download / view stats on specific PDF files on their website.

It seems that Google Analytics provides two options: event tracking and virtual pageviews. But, the documentation is not clear to me whether either of these is tracking actual file loads vs. clicks. It seems to me that if the options are tracking clicks on an HTML link on a page, then views from entering the address in the address bar, and clicks from other technologies, such as email would be missed.

It is also my understanding that the basic structural problem is that PDF files cannot contain the JavaScript code from the Google API.

My question is: have I misunderstood how the options work?

Comment: Don't know about how GA would handle this, but it is *trivial* to do it by processing the log files for your server. This was a solved problem back in 1995.

Comment: True, but my client is more comfortable with GA, so I am hoping to find a solution that he finds most efficient.

Comment: OK, so one way would be to create a separate "download page" (a trivial PHP (or whatever) script to send the file). That page/script would have the necessary GA info and thus be counted regardless of how it was accessed. If you have a non-empty HTTP-REFERER you can then bounce them back where they came from.

Comment: While I think through your implementation suggestion, it occurs to me that it contains the implicit answer that both event tracking and virtual pageviews do not track loads but clicks.

Comment: Uhm, I'm no GA expert, but from when I lasted used it I remember it was from the page load itself. They may now also support something like tracking a click that happens on a one-page-website (which I loathe because those sites breaks the RESTful contract of URLs), but that click still, in some sense, leads to a page load.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You understood the options correctly.

Google Analytics does not usually track file downloads. The default tracker is a javascript implementation, so it can track views of pages that execute javascript or click on links - you can implement link clicks to pdf documents as (virtual) pageviews if you want to, but ultimately it is the link that is tracked, not the document itself.

There is in fact a a way to implement GA serverside (via the [measurement protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/), a language agnostic protocol for http calls to the Google servers), but that suffers more or less from the same problem that a logfile analyses would - the point of Google Analytics is to embed individual user actions into a larger context (what traffic source did the user come from, what did he before and after, is he a returning or a new visitor etc.) and that context gets easily lost if you mix client- and serverside implementations (pageviews are grouped into sessions, sessions are grouped into users; a new user is registered when client id changes, a new sessions starts when for an existing client id the traffic source changes, which very likely happens when you switch between client- and serverside tracking). You could of course implement GA completely on the server side, but then you'd have to maintain a unique client id per user yourself and find a solution for event tracking (for events like link tracking that do not usually cause entries in a server log file).

Having said that tracking the download link instead of the file itself is what most people do, usually with some kind of intermediate download script that prevents hotlinking. If you want to register this as event or virtual pageview is a matter of taste - my clients as a rule use virtual pageviews for documents that typically open in the browser (pdf) and events for everything else, the idea being that users might return from the pdf to an existing GA session.

Answer (score 1):

I believe using Google Tag Manager narrows down the possibility of error between clicks and actual downloads. The triggers allow you to validate clicks, wait before an event is fired. Simo Ahava has explained it well https://www.simoahava.com/gtm-tips/track-file-downloads-in-gtm-v2/

Comment: I have read the article, and am uncertain whether the suggestions work when someone types the path directly into the address bar or clicks a link from an email. If you found that in the article, could you specify where?